# 400 Bad Request nginx/1.13.12

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx

I am getting "400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port nginx/1.13.12" upon Nginx/Docker/SSL configuration. Below is my SSL configuration inside Docker container of Nginx. Please help.

```
server {
    listen          80;
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     mydomain.com;
    root            /usr/share/etc/nginx;
    index           index.html index.htm index.php;

    if ($scheme = http) 
    {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.key;

     ssl_session_timeout 5m;


     location /{
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;  
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

            proxy_pass                      http://localhost;
            proxy_read_timeout              180;

            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_redirect   http://localhost $scheme://mydomain.com;

            proxy_http_version              1.1;
            proxy_request_buffering         off;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Execute `lsof -i :443` and `lsof -i :80` to see wht's listening on these ports and post the result here.

Comment: Hi @SaqibAhmed, Thanks for your response. Here what I get upon running those commands inside nginx docker container. But I don't get anything when I run the commands outside the container (on host). But firewall ports on host for both ports are open. Anyway clue?    
   nginx     1 root    6u  IPv4 238369      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN),nginx   /  1 root    7u  IPv4 238370      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)